# Reading values from JSON in Node.js in GET request

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, get, alexa-skills-kit

I need to pull the Indication value from the following

```
{
    "records": [{
        "id": "recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo",
        "fields": {
            "DrugName": "azatadine",
            "nameapi": ["recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"],
            "Indication": "For the relief of the symptoms of upper respiratory mucosal congestion in perennial and allergic rhinitis, and for the relief of nasal congestion and eustachian t.b. congestion.",
            "lookup": ["azatadine"],
            "drugID": "recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"
        },
        "createdTime": "2018-11-09T19:38:24.000Z"
    }]
 }
```

When I try to do 
`response.records[0].fields.Indication`
I get the error 
`Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
function httpGet() {

return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

var options = {

host: 'api.airtable.com',

port: 443,

path: '/v0/appYqfJ3Rt2F0sRGn/Database?filterByFormula=(DrugName=%27azatadine%27)',

method: 'GET',

headers: {

Authorization: 'Bearer key123456789'

}

};

const request = https.request(options, (response) => {

response.setEncoding('utf8');

let returnData = '';

response.on('data', (chunk) => {

returnData += chunk;

});

response.on('end', () => {

resolve(returnData);

});

response.on('error', (error) => {

reject(error);

});

});

request.end();

}));

}



const UserReplyIntent_Handler = {

canHandle(handlerInput) {

const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'UserReplyIntent' ;

},

async handle(handlerInput) {

const response = await httpGet();

console.log(response);

return handlerInput.responseBuilder

.speak("Okay. Here we go" + response.records[0].fields.Indication)

.reprompt("say again")

.getResponse();

},

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON isn’t really JSON yet at this stage. You need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the result you get from your Ajax request to then work with it as native JSON.

The response is stringified when it gets delivered to you, that parse command will in stringify it for you.

You can do this as part of a `then` chain after your promise (probably best practice) or do it right inside your promise.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example of how to do that? Sorry I'm a total noob at this

Comment: Actually, the best way to do this is probably `response.json()` - A good example is shown on MDN which will probably explain things better than I can here, and I’d just be referring to that article anyway, so I won’t plagiarize them :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Answer (score 0):

I was missing json.parse

```
.then((response) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(response);
 for (let i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {
 if (i === 0) {
     outputSpeech = outputSpeech +  'The name of the drug is' + data.records[i].fields.DrugName +  ', '
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the json.parse method

```
.then((response) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(response);
 for (let i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {
 if (i === 0) {
     outputSpeech = outputSpeech +  'The name of the drug is' + data.records[i].fields.DrugName +  ', '
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to do this with asynchronous responses is to do the following:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
  //response is now a JSON object that you can be worked with
})
```